# Why isn't software USB/TTL on ATmega328p working?

Tags: arduino, usb, avr, atmega328p

I've tried to implement an AVR-CDC project. I found [this](http://www.recursion.jp/prose/avrcdc/) website which is recommended by [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/projects.html) (I know it is pretty old project.)

I drew this schematic:

[image]

I've built a PCB basef on it and then I've uploaded the ATmega328p HEX file into the chip.

The problem is when I connected it to my PC, it dorsn't recognize anything and nothing appears as USB or ttyX (I'm on Ubuntu) or when I connect it to Arduino Pro Mini through RX-TX-Vcc-GNF pins nothing appears.

I've tested USB port is fine because it powers the main board. The ATmega328p chip is Ok because I can program it through SPI connector.  The Arduino is fine because I can program it with another USB/TTL module.  The PCB is fine because I did a continuity test on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where are your D+ and D- lines from USB micro going?

Comment: PD3 and PD2 are connected to D+ and D-

Comment: you need a USB driver that can be detected by your computer as a COM port and takes care of USB protocol. Signal lines PD3 and PD2 are just digital lines. how will they assume a USB connection?

Comment: @DavidNorman the USB is implemented as a bitbang software USB with the V-USB library.

Comment: The README file provided by this site said: In Unix OS it don't need a driver and it recognize it as ttyACM-X. I assume it simulate it programmatically in the code, there is no driver for linux.

Comment: You appear to have attempted to connect two distinct net labels VCC and AVCC.  That probably didn't happen as most software will not allow it.   Check your electrical connectivity to the power pins.

Answer (score 0):

You have powered the AVR with 5V from USB so it uses 5V IO voltage. USB data pins are 3.3V signals and your schematics have nothing to limit the voltage except the 68R seris resistors to limit the current to 25mA so unplug the device before it damages your PC.

If the USB port of PC is not yet damaged, there are other reasons as well. The fuse bits must be set to use external crystal, and the crystal speed must match what the programmed binary expects.

Comment: It took me some time to build another board, and I disconnect the 5V power from USB to board, but it didn't help.

Comment: But it won't work without a power supply, right?

Comment: Do U really think I'm that kind of dude. If U look at the schematic, I've put power supply pin header on the PCB for these situations.

Comment: I don't know anything about you or what you are doing so I am just trying to figure out what you are doing to help you. What is the crystal frequency? Please note that if you are feeding 3.3V to the MCU, with that voltage it cannot run at 16MHz, it can only run at up to 8 MHz.